# getting contact from phonebook in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have Got Two Array List NumINdb(VARIABLES) and common(VARIABLES)...I Have Compared Two Arraylist and Retrieved Common Elements from the Arraylist in a New Arraylist Finalarr(VARIABLE)...

I am Passing the Arraylist to a Function getPlayers(Finalarr).....Below is the Function...

I have Phone numbers in the FinalArr Arraylist and Want Their names From the Contact Book / Phone book of the phone....I want to Store the Value in a Arraylist...

```
 private ArrayList < DATA_CONTACT > getPlayers(ArrayList < String > filterVALUES) {
    ArrayList < DATA_CONTACT > players = new ArrayList < DATA_CONTACT > ();

    ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();

    Cursor phoneCursor;
    for (int o = 0; o < filterVALUES.size(); o++) {

        phoneCursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " = ?", new String[] {
                filterVALUES.get(o).toString()
            }, null);

        DATA_CONTACT p = null;
        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {

            p = new DATA_CONTACT();
            final String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contact_display_name = phoneCursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            // filtered.add(phoneNumber.toString());

            p.setName(contact_display_name);
            p.setPhone(phoneNumber.toString());
            p.setImg(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_like_background);
        }
        phoneCursor.close();
        players.add(p);

    }
    return players; //Returns a List of Contact Matching the Arraylist..
}
```

Error...

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.cosmic.zumi_test, PID: 534
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.cosmic.zumi_test.Contact_FRAGMENT3.getPlayers(Contact_FRAGMENT3.java:243)
                                                   at com.example.cosmic.zumi_test.Contact_FRAGMENT3.access$100(Contact_FRAGMENT3.java:57)
                                                   at com.example.cosmic.zumi_test.Contact_FRAGMENT3$1.onDataChange(Contact_FRAGMENT3.java:157)
                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                   at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: I dont understand what it is you want from us? That we write code for you? Meaning: please do not only talk about what you **want** to do; but explain what **prevents** you getting there. Besides: you want us to spend our time to help you; so you please take the 1 min it takes to properly format/indent your source code. Long story short: spent some time here [help] and read what/how to ask here.

Comment: @ghostCAT I have  Put my Error Message..I am Getting..Pls Help...

Comment: That makes more sense (still: why the lazy formatting for the stack trace) ... anyway: start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I want Help with my Query i have Passed...Pls Check... VARIABLE contact_display_name is giving Null Error...

Comment: Dont just talk about what you *want*. Take the time to digest the feedback you already got; especially that link in my **second** comment; besides: you got an answer already.

Comment: i totally fantasise about lower-casing this entire question...

Comment: @marmor Collecting 105 rep during two hours of being online makes me smile. Reading your comment made me laugh! I hope I just made you smile too by improving your question track record ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The exception points (most likely?) here:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(...
```

and tells you that **cursor** is **null**.

Did you mean *phoneCursor* instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get only names from array list(I am assuming your array list contains numbers) then below is the method that returns name against contact number.

```
public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

Don't forget to add 'read contact' permission in manifest